# Algebra and exponential functions

Tags: logarithms

Given $x^n=y$ where $n=y$, I have no problem finding $x$ if $y$ is known. Problem is getting $y$ when only the value of $x$ is known. Is there a way? At the moment I'm working with $x$ and $y$ values less than $1$.
Thanks.

Comment: In the elementary functions it's impossible.

Comment: $\ln(x^y)=y\ln(x)$

Answer (score 1):

So you are trying to solve for $y$ in the equation $x^y = y$.

The Lambert W function is useful for this.

$x^y=y \implies x^{-y} = y^{-1} \implies yx^{-y}=1 => ye^{-\ln(x)y} =1$

Multiply by $-\ln x$ on both sides:

$-y\ln xe^{-y\ln x}=-\ln x$

Now use the Lambert W function on both sides.

$-y\ln x=W(-\ln x) \implies y=-\frac {W(-\ln x)}{\ln x}$
For $x \lt 1$, $W(-\ln x)$ is well defined, so this is our solution.

Comment: Wow! I would never have found that on my own. I struggled for the past couple of days in vain. A couple of hours ago I got a hunch (epiphany?) Natural logarithm is involved somehow. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have found a way that does not require Natural logarithm. It is repeated iteration with Common Logarithm (decidic). Is that new or it's an obsolete method?

Comment: can you share your function for y in terms of x (y(x))?

Comment: Sure. x^y=y means log to base x of y is y. Therefore [math]log(y)/y=log(x)[/math]

Comment: Yes, this is trivial. However it does not help you find y for a given x like my solution.

Comment: You are right @ Abhishek. My bad.

Comment: This is what I meant to write in full. y=log(y)/log(x). From here I propose an iterative method of finding the value of y when x is given. y'=y/2+log (y)/2log(x)

Comment: yes you could Euler's Method to approximate y using the easily known solution (1,1) or any other known solution, however Euler's Method is very inaccurate for far away x and with anything but a miniscule step.

Answer (score 0):

If $$x^n=y$$ so we get $$x=\sqrt[n]{y}$$